# Cross-domain PHP calls using jQuery and AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, email

I have a problem where the server I'm using is not configured to allow PHP or CGI and I need to send a mail using variables received from a form on this server to the owner, like a general enquiry/feedback form.

Does anyone know how I can call a simple PHP file on another domain configured to use PHP and then execute the `mail()` function on that server with variables passed to it from my non-PHP/CGI server?

How do I enable cross-domain AJAX calls without the originating server having PHP/CGI enabled?

Any feedback/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably somehow doable using JSONP, but you don't need Javascript for this. The much easier solution would be to place the sending PHP script on the remote server, e.g.

```
 www.serverwithphp.com/send.php
```

and then to point the feedback form directly to that script:

```
 <form action="http://www.serverwithphp.com/send.php" ....>
```

and have `send.php` do a header redirect back to the original site after sending:

```
 header("Location: http://www.serverwithoutphp.com/thanks.htm");
 die();
```

Comment: Thanks, I never thought of it that way. I'll try it first thing tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 0):

On applications supporting it, you can do it with [JSONP](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/?ca=dgr-jw64JSONP-jQuery&S_TACT=105AGY46&S_CMP=grsitejw64)