# Session checking on $.ajax() request from other domain

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery `$.ajax` code on domain A and a domain B ([PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) server).

- Step 1: the user already logged in on PHP server [B],
- Step 2: the user comes to domain A and sends an Ajax request (having only an empty string) to the PHP server

Can I check the session of that user to find his username on the PHP server? Is it possible?

Comment: i have not started coding anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session cookies would be sent automatically. If the user is logged in to server B before the ajax call is made, the server B session token should be sent along with the ajax request. However, note that ajax calls are subject to the same origin security policy - code loaded from server A will not able to issue ajax calls to server B, as that's not the same server. There's [methods to work around this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078909/cross-domain-php-calls-using-jquery-and-ajax), but they're not as nice as a simple `.ajax()` call.